# Facebook like pop-up dialogue is cut off to the width of the button

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-like

Check out my blog here:

http://www.brixwork.com/realtors/blog/seo/best-time-to-post-on-facebook-or-twitter-and-email/

When you try to click the "LIKE" button, the pop up comes up at the right height, but the width is restricted to the width of the button.

Here's my CSS code:

```
.blog_social_media {
    float: right;
    border-left: 1px dotted #666;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    overflow: visible;
}

.blog_social_media div {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}

iframe.fb_ltr {
    width: 300px !important;
}

.blog_twitter_button {
    width: 55px;
    height: 62px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

.blog_facebook_button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 63px;
    overflow: visible !important;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

.blog_googleplus_button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
```

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="blog_social_media" style="width:65px; height:auto;">
    <div class="blog_twitter_button">
        <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="vertical" data-via="brixwork" data-related="sonikastudios">Tweet</a>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div class="blog_facebook_button">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.brixwork.com/realtors/blog/seo/three-reasons-to-claim-your-place-on-google-places/" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="50" data-show-faces="false" data-font="lucida grande">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog_googleplus_button">
        <!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
        <g:plusone size="tall"></g:plusone>

        <!-- Place this render call where appropriate -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function() {
                var po = document.createElement('script'); 
                po.type = 'text/javascript'; 
                po.async = true;
                po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
            })();
        </script>
    </div>                  
</div>
```

I have overflow:visible; set on all my elements that enclose the facebook balloon. The same CSS logic works just fine on the Google+ popup dialogue, just the Facebook one is choking. What's going on that I can fix?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm seeing this too.. what a pain!

Comment: @jeffkee did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
.fb_edge_widget_with_comment span
{overflow:visible !important; width:450px !important; margin-right:-375px;}
```

Put that in your css, it will set the size of the popup to its *undeclared* size and will reduce the overwidth by negative margining.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a problem with:

```
<div class="blog_facebook_button">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.brixwork.com/realtors/blog/seo/three-reasons-to-claim-your-place-on-google-places/" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="50" data-show-faces="false" data-font="lucida grande">
    </div>
</div>
```

The attr data-width="50" needs to be data-width="250" and then you need to add

```
.blog_facebook_button { position: relative; }
.fb-like { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
```

Comment: It might need some adjustment because I couldn't test it properly.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
.fb-like span {
  overflow:visible !important; width:450px !important; margin-right:-400px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

looks like div.fb-like -> span is cutting it off try CSS:

```
div.fb-like span {
    width: 450px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```